# How to select and save choosen columns from csv in python

Tags: python, csv, exiftool

I visual artist and photographer working for agencies. When I am uploading photos, I need to send an csv file also, which I generating by exiftool.
My problem is, exiftool generates makes 100+ columns, but I need only 3 colums from the whole csv file

1., I need simplify somehow this csv file, and export 3 selected columns (SourceFile, Description, ObjectName) as new file.

2., The column SourceFile contains paths like "photos/9456.jpg" and I need only the filename "9456.jpg" without path.

[Link to generated example csv by exiftool](https://1drv.ms/u/s!ArpdPE3VDFapuLAVTl7HRW3C5-t41A?e=59WYRi)

Could any good person help me solve this in python? Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried so far? We're much more here to help with specific questions of the form "I tried X, but it did not do what I expect and instead resulted in an error!" accompanied by a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Instead of putting a link that some cautious users could be reluctant to follow, you'd better copy the first lines of the generated file **as text** in the question itself, and put also as text what you would like as a result. BTW, the way to solve this is the `csv` module of the standard Python Library...

Comment: Try using pandas. There's a read_csv function that will let you read a file in, and then you can manipulate the data and write it back out.

Answer (score 0):

List only the tags you need when you run exiftool.  For example
`exiftool -Filename -Description -ObjectName -csv >out.csv /path/to/files/`
Will create a csv file with only the SourceFile (cannot be suppressed), `Filename`, `Description`, and `ObjectName` tags.

See the exiftool docs on the [`-csv` option](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#csv-CSVFILE) and [exiftool FAQ #12](https://exiftool.org/faq.html#Q12).

Comment: Thanks it worked for me.